# Function call overhead in C DLL for Python

Tags: python, arrays, c, include, shared-libraries

So I want to use a C DLL in Python, I have a code that works. My problem is the performance/computation time. When I call my C Code in a main function in C it is very fast (0.0 - 0.1 s). However calling it as a DLL, it is very slow (3 - 4 s).

After some trial and error, I figured out that the problem are the functions called from the C includes such as `math.h`. That's why have my own `abs()` and `pow()` function defined. The main issue is in the nested for loops. But for the `cos()` and `sin()` functions I don't have my own solution and I actually don't want to implement every library function myself.

Why are the C includes causing that much overhead? Do you have to bind the includes to Python or is there any trick?

Thanks in advance.

Python Code:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np
import _ctypes

# load dll
VVdll = ctypes.CDLL('./ViterbiViterbi', winmode=0x8)

# Define the function argument types
VVdll.ViterbiViterbi.argtypes = [
    np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, ndim=2, flags="C"),  # sigs_in
    np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, ndim=2, flags="C"),  # sigs_out
    ctypes.c_int,  # Nsymb
    ctypes.c_int,  # Nsig
    ctypes.c_int,  # nCPE
    np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, ndim=2, flags="C")  # theta_rec
]

# Define the function return type
VVdll.ViterbiViterbi.restype = None

# Example usage
Nsig, Nsymb = data.shape
nCPE = 100

sigs_in = data.values

# Create input and output arrays
sigs_in_r = sigs_in.real
sigs_in_i = sigs_in.imag
sigs_in_r = np.ascontiguousarray(sigs_in_r, dtype=np.float64)
sigs_in_i = np.ascontiguousarray(sigs_in_i, dtype=np.float64)

theta_rec = np.zeros_like(sigs_in, dtype=float )

theta_rec = np.ascontiguousarray(theta_rec, dtype=np.float64)

sigs_in_r = np.asarray(sigs_in_r, order='C')
sigs_in_i = np.asarray(sigs_in_i, order='C')
theta_rec = np.asarray(theta_rec, order='C')

# Call the function
VVdll.ViterbiViterbi(sigs_in_r, sigs_in_i, Nsymb, Nsig, nCPE, theta_rec)

theta_rec = np.unwrap(theta_rec*4, axis=1)/4

sigs_out = sigs_in*np.exp( -1j*theta_rec)
data_rec = sigs_out
_ctypes.FreeLibrary(VVdll._handle)
```

C Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif

double myabs(double r, double i) {
    return sqrt(r*r + i*i);
}

double mypow4(double x) {
    double x2 = x * x;
    double x4 = x2 * x2;
    return x4;
}

double atan2_alternative(double y, double x) {
    return atan2(y, x);
}

DLL00_EXPORT_API void ViterbiViterbi(double *sigs_in_r, double *sigs_in_i, int Nsymb, int Nsig, int nCPE, double *theta_rec) {
    double *sumv_r = (double*)calloc(Nsymb, sizeof(double));
    double *sumv_i = (double*)calloc(Nsymb, sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < Nsig * Nsymb; i += Nsymb) {
        int start = (i - Nsymb * nCPE) > 0 ? (i - Nsymb * nCPE) : 0;
        int stop = (i + Nsymb * nCPE) < (Nsymb * Nsig - 2) ? (i + Nsymb * nCPE) : (Nsymb * Nsig - 2);

        for (int k = 0; k < Nsymb; k++) {
            double abs_val_pow4 = mypow4(myabs(sigs_in_r[start + k], sigs_in_i[start + k]));

            sumv_r[k] = 0.0;
            sumv_i[k] = 0.0;

            for (int j = start; j <= stop; j += Nsymb) {
                double real_part = sigs_in_r[j + k];
                double imag_part = sigs_in_i[j + k];
                double arg_val = atan2_alternative(imag_part, real_part);

                sumv_r[k] += abs_val_pow4 * cos(4 * arg_val);
                sumv_i[k] += abs_val_pow4 * sin(4 * arg_val);
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < Nsymb; k++) {
            theta_rec[i + k] = (0.25) * atan2_alternative(sumv_i[k], sumv_r[k]) - 0.25 * M_PI;
        }
    }

    free(sumv_r);
    free(sumv_i);
}
```

I compile like that: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O -ansi -pedantic -shared -std=c99 ViterbiViterbi.c -o ViterbiViterbi.dll`

Comment: -O may or may not be enough, try -O2. Also, `mypow4(myabs(...))` is a waste of `sqrt`. Don't use `abs` or any alternative, you only need abs-squared (i.e. re^2 + im^2), and then square that.

Comment: You may also want to show your `main` function in C, and any data file you use to test it, so that we can try and reproduce your problem.